# How do you assign the return value of a utility (grep/sed) to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to create a shell script to make a Makefile. My strategy is to create two arrays, one containing all the .cpp files, and another with the .cpp suffixes replaces by .o. I then assign the .h and .ccp files from the return value of (grep | sed) to variable temp and then print the arrays. I keep getting the error however:
"syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".o"
My theory is that the return value for grep is not storing in temp correctly
I am very new to bash

```
cppfield=$(ls *.cpp)
x=0
for i in *.cpp; do
  ofield[$x]="${i%.cpp}.o"
done


echo "$1 : ${ofield[@]}" > Makefile
echo "  g++ -ansi -Wall -g -o $1 ${ofield[@]}" >> Makefile

for i in "${ofield[@]}"; do
  temp=$(grep '#include "' ${cppfield[i]} | sed s/#include// | sed s/\"//g)
  echo "${ofield[i]} : ${cppfield[i]} ${temp[@]}" >> Makefile
  echo "    g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c ${cppfield[i]}" >> Makefile
done
```

Comment: `grep '#include "${cppfield[i]}'`  - is it because you're passing two arguments to grep (because the quotes don't cover the variable as well)?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is find the dependencies, which is probably better done by `g++ -MM` - it produces a dependency list for the file(s) you specified, that you can include/use in a makefile.

See the bottom of this file, my makefiles often contain something like this:

```
include .depends

.depends: Makefile ${SOURCES}
    ${CXX} -MM ${CXXFLAGS} ${SOURCES} > $@
```

Full file:
https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/Makefile

Your grep solution works reasonably well until you do something like:

```
 #if _WIN32
 #include <windows.h>
 #else
 #include <someother.h>
 #endif
```

or

```
 /* Don't need this any more...
 #include "blah.h
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ declare -a my_array
$ my_array=(`ls -1 *.cpp`)
$ echo ${my_array[0]}
a.cpp
$ echo ${my_array[1]}
b.cpp
```